# Present ViewController modaly inside tab bar loaded viewcontroler

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `TabBarController` in which I have the main ViewController which implements `UIWebView`, when there's no connection it presents modaly ErrorViewController which have a retry button that dismiss the view and, on completition, reloads the webview. I would like to get the modal displayed inside the tab bar view (where is the WebView) allowing the user to continue navigating over the tabs.

I'm currently using `performSegue(withIdentifier: "showErrorView", sender: self)` but it covers the whole screen.

I've tried to use a `NavigationController` but when I pop the view I didn't find how to tell to the ViewController which is shown on pop to reload the WebView (In other words, I don't have a competition handler)

### Images

### [App before modal appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiwv6.png)

### [Current behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo8Hk.png)

### [Expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uulq.jpg)

Comment: is "showErrorView" segue connected between mainVC to ErrorVC or TabBarVC to ErrorVC?

Comment: @Anand to the main VC

Comment: When you use NavigationController, it is displayed correctly..right? but only problem in that case is not able to reload the webview?

Comment: @Anand you’re right

Comment: When you present a view controller, that view controller is designed to take over the UI. The user is not expected to be allowed to continue navigating throughout the app. That's the concept of modals in general. Therefore, what you need is not a modal presentation. You just need a view that that specific view controller displays (allowing the user to continue navigating to other tabs).

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, select the present modal segue and select presentation as `Over Current Context` instead of `Over full Screen`

[image]

Comment: It still happening the same, there's another option which is only current context, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Finally I've added a navigation controller to the first tab where first navigation items is the mainVC which on webView connection fail presents modaly the ErrorVC (with the code I posted before) which presentation is configured as Over current context, and It works as expected and when retry button is pressed is dismissed and reloads the webview ok. All works ok until you change the tab while errorView is presented and then return to the first tab when dismiss it, the mainView not loads it aprears in black and when the erro tries to reopen the modal says MainVC is not in the window hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You can set Delegate (`Protocol`) method to communicate back to MainVC from ErrorVC to reload the webview when is is dismissed.

**Delegate**

```
protocol WebViewDelegate: class {
    func reloadWebView()
}
```

**ErrorVC**

```
class ErrorVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: WebViewDelegate?

    @IBAction func retryButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        delegate. reloadWebView()
    }
}
```

**MainVC**

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, WebViewDelegate {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let errorVC = segue.destination as? ErrorVC {
            errorVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func reloadWebView() {
        // reload code
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally I've added a navigation controller to the first tab where first navigation items is the mainVC which on webView connection fail presents modaly the ErrorVC  (with the code I posted before) which presentation is configured as Over current context, and It works as expected and when retry button is pressed is dismissed and reloads the webview ok. All works ok until you change the tab while errorView is presented and then return to the first tab when dismiss it, the mainView not loads it aprears in black and when the erro tries to reopen the modal says MainVC is not in the window hierarchy

Comment: So, whenever you switch to other tabs when error view is presented, can you dismiss it and switch? Think about it !

Comment: Yes, when I’ve dismissed the errorVc and the main tan is en black I van switch to Other tabs, what is more, when I switch to other tab and return to the first tab the main view is correctly loaded again